# xml file validating in notepad++ but not in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xsd snippet:

```
    <xs:element name="TR" type="tns:blah" />
<xs:complexType name="blah">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Res" type="tns:Res" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SNotifications" type="tns:ArrayOfSNotification" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UNotifications" type="tns:ArrayOfUNotification" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TNotifications" type="tns:ArrayOfTNotification" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

and I have the following xml:

```
    <TR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://something.com/something">
  <Res>
    <CC>CMG</CC>
    <CT>2014-07-24T14:10:03.84</CT>
    <BN>994807</BN>
  </Res>
  <SNotifications xmlns="http://something.com/something" />
  <UNotifications xmlns="http://something.com/something" />
  <TNotifications xmlns="http://something.com/something" />
</TR>
```

I get no error validation the xml in notepad++.

but i get an error while using C#.

The error is:
 exception:System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: The element 'TR' in namespace 'http://something.com/something' has invalid child element 'SNotifications'. List of possible elements expected: 'SNotifications, TNotifications, UNotifications'

the C# code i use is:

```
xmlDocument.Schemas.Add("http://www.something.com/something", "path to xsd file");
    string result = string.Empty;
    xmlDocument.Validate((s, e) => result = string.Format("exception:{0}, exceptionmessage:{1}", e.Exception, e.Message));
```

I have already loaded the xml document.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
gmat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
public static bool IsValidXml(string xmlFilePath, string xsdFilePath)
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
    var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemas.Add(namespaceName, xsdFilePath);

    Boolean result = true;
    xdoc.Validate(schemas, (sender, e) =>
         {
             result = false;
         });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you Janty, but unfortunately I cannot use XDocument. I am coding against .net version 3.0. Do you have something that would work against an older version?

Comment: I used an xmldocument version of this

Answer (score 0):

We need to know the targetNamespace of your schema document, and the setting of elementFormDefault. Almost certainly it's one of the following:

(a) you have elementFormDefault="qualified", and the target namespace of the schema is not http://something.com/something (in which case the SNotifications element should be in the target namespace); or

(b) you don't have elementFormDefault="qualified" (in which case SNotifications should be in no namespace).